# "Undefined" when trying to use web3Provider.network

Tags: web3js, javascript

I want to get network chainId from web3Provider.
This is my code.

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";
const web3provider = isBrowser ? new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum) : null;

const currentChainId = web3provider.network.chainId;
```

But I get this error.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chainId')

Please tell me how can I access network attribute in web3provider.
(Documentation says it's not safe way to access web3provider._network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `await` the network with `getNetwork()` ([docs here](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getNetwork)), and then access the id with `network.chainId` ([docs here](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-Network)).

Here is some example code:

```js
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";
const web3provider = isBrowser ? new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum) : null;

// await network and return chainId
async function getCurrentChainId() {
  if (!web3provider) return null;
  const network = await web3provider.getNetwork();
  return network.chainId;
}

// await async function
const currentChainId = await getCurrentChainId();

// log the chainId
console.log(currentChainId);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: awesome. feel free to accept the answer so that it no longer appears in the open questions.